# How to grab all attachments [video, images] from a post and display in a UL in template

Tags: wordpress

I wrote some code that displays all attachment images in a UL to sidescroll on a custom post type.  client now wants video returned too. Right now, I'm using a regex to parse all the images from the post but it's not grabbing video. Also, I hate depending on regex as it is impossible to also grab url etc with present implementation.

Is there a way to grab all attachments associated with a post (not including the custom-field-thumbnail), and then populate the attachments in a  element on the page?

Answer (score 0):

This would call all your attachment types - just add extra statements for other mime types (png, gif etc.)

```
    <?php 
$thumb_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
$attachments = get_posts(array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'exclude' => $thumb_ID,
    ));

if ( $attachments ) {   
foreach( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    $attachment_mime = wp_check_filetype(wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID) );
            $title = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title );
            if ( $attachment_mime['type'] == 'image/jpeg') {echo '<li><img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) . '" alt="'.$title.'"  /></li>'; }
            elseif( $attachment_mime['type'] == 'video/mp4'){echo '<li><video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls data-setup="{}"><source src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ).'" type="video/mp4" /></video></li>';}           
}
}?>
```